# Using urllib to get the final redirect of a webpage in Python 3.5

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, python-3.5, urllib

As in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3556266/how-can-i-get-the-final-redirect-url-when-using-urllib2-urlopen), I attempt to get the final redirect of a webpage as:

```
import urllib.request
response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
response.geturl()
```

But this doesn't work as I get the "HTTPError: HTTP Error 300: Multiple Choices" error when attempting to use `urlopen`.

See documentation for these methods [here](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/urllib.request.html#module-urllib.request).

**EDIT:**

This problem is different than the [Python: urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 300: Multiple Choices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32641862/python-urllib2-httperror-http-error-300-multiple-choices) question, because they skip the error-causing pages, while I have to obtain the final destination.

Comment: Why don’t you use the requests library? It’s much easier for dealing with this kind of situation

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 300: Multiple Choices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32641862/python-urllib2-httperror-http-error-300-multiple-choices)

Comment: @mx0 That post addresses the same issue, but while they are skipping the redirected pages, I actually have to follow the link and obtain the final destination.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @abccd, I used the `requests` library. So I will describe the solution.

```
import requests

url_base = 'something'  # You need this because the redirect URL is relative.
url = url_base + 'somethingelse'

response = requests.get(url)

# Check if the request returned with the 300 error code.
if response.status_code == 300:
    redirect_url = url_base + response.headers['Location']  # Get new URL.
    response = requests.get(redirect_url)  # Make a new request.
```